# South data migration update across tables

Tags: django, orm, django-south, data-migration

I have this migration:

```
book_metas = orm.DigitalProductFormat.objects.exclude(image__isnull=True)
    for book_meta in book_metas:
        book_meta.checksum = book_meta.image.checksum
        book_meta.save()
```

If a book has an image, then move the checksum from the image to the book.  There are near 1,000,000 books and this migration is taking forever.  Is there a nice way to reduce the number of times I have to call save

I looked at using Django's queryset update method but that doesn't seem to be able to work across tables.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do this migration is to use raw SQL query.

I don't know if your database supports `UPDATE ... FROM ... JOIN` syntax but the following `UPDATE ... SELECT`  should work almost on every db-server.

```
from south.db import db
db.execute("""
    UPDATE app_digitalproductformat
    SET checksum = (SELECT checksum FROM app_image
                    WHERE app_image.id=app_digitalproductformat.image_id)
    WHERE image_id IS NOT NULL
           """)
```

Where `app` is the name of your django app.

Comment: Thanks!, I was hoping to avoid going into raw sql for it, but if its the only way I will.